# How to make Dapper resilient for SqlAzure?

Tags: azure-sql-database, dapper, resiliency

I recently found out Entity Framework has a very easy way to make connections resilient in SQL Azure. Is there a recommended way to accomplish the same in Dapper?

Comment: Dapper is just a wrapper around ADO.NET; what *exactly* do you mean by "make ... resilient" here? what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I want all Execute and Query calls I make in Dapper to survive minor cloud problems caused by Azure. Following this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/17/net-framework-4-5-1-rtm-gt-start-coding.aspx it means I could just upgrade my framework to 4.5.1 and ADO.Net connections to SQL Azure environmnet will automatically be resilient?

Comment: No @JakobLithner that won't be enough.  That link only discusses connection disconnects.  It doesn't mention transient errors which is the main concern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fastest way to protect against connection issues in C# against Azure is the  [Microsoft Transient Fault Handling Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

For example the below code would retry upto 3 times with 1 second intervals in-between when attempting to open a connection to a Windows Azure SQL Database:

```
var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var retryPolicy = 
  new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => myConnection.Open());
```

`FixedInterval` is the back off policy, so it will try, wait 1 second, try again, etc until it's tried 3 times.

`SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy` is simply does a check on the exception thrown, if it's a connection exception that should be retried, it will tell the `RetryPolicy` to execute the action again.  If it is not a connection exception, then the action will not be executed and the original exception will be thrown as normal.

As for when you should use it with Dapper; you can safely retry opening connections and read operations, however be aware or retrying write operations as there is a risk of duplicating inserts, trying to delete a row twice etc.

More detail [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling), this library can be found as a [NuGet Package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling/) which includes the detection strategies for Windows Azure.